# Software to cut out rectangular photos from a scan

Tags: photography, scanning

I will be scanning a lot of pictures (regular family pictures, none of them will overlap, the scanner is decent, but not professional quality, they won't be alligned 100%) and I want the scanned pictures to be split up into separated files. So I need the software to basically find and "cut out" the pictures. If this does not exist, I'll of course have to resort to writing this myself.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I follow. Are you saying that if the image is lightly rotated when laid on the scanner, then you want a rectangle which is all image, with not scanner-bed, thus throwing away some of the original image?

Comment: Let's say I put 10 images on the scanner-bed. Of course I'm not a machine, so I can't put them 100% straight on them, with equal space between them. I basically want a separate file for every different picture, with in it the picture cut out and rotated so it's completely straight.

Comment: @SteveBarnes upvoted answers are sufficient for duplicates. OP might never return to accept.